# How to execute a function inside if without being repetitive if the condition is not met?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, relayjs

This is code for relay mutation, I have to do this reload so the store will be in sync with the database because for some reason if the text is same as the previously added text relay store throws an error flattenChildren...

```
  _handleTextInputSave = (text) => {
    if(checkIfTextAlreadyExists(text) && window.confirm("Todo already exists! Please confirm to proceed.")) {
      AddTodoMutation.commit(
        this.props.relay.environment,
        text,
        this.props.viewer,
      );
     location.reload();
    }
    AddTodoMutation.commit(
      this.props.relay.environment,
      text,
      this.props.viewer,
    );
  };
```

I cannot think of other way because I have to reload if text already exists but somehow I feel AddTodoMutation.commit is redundant. What do you think? I would appreciate suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you always want to commit and only do the reload conditionally. So write that:

```
_handleTextInputSave = (text) => {
  const exists = checkIfTextAlreadyExists(text) && window.confirm("Todo already exists! Please confirm to proceed.");
  AddTodoMutation.commit(
    this.props.relay.environment,
    text,
    this.props.viewer,
  );
  if (exists)
    location.reload();
};
```

Comment: yes! I have not thought of that way. thank u so much